# Как в питоне переместить данные из одной переменной в другую?

Tags: python

Нужно переместить `'Пирог'` из списка `box` в список `box_1`.
Мой код:

```
box = ['Пирог', 'мороженное', 'вафли']
box_1 = []
```

Comment: [Функции и методы списков](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/spiski-list-funkcii-i-metody-spiskov.html)

Comment: Что означает "переместить" ? Почему именно "пирог"?

Answer (score 5):

если в box нужно удалить пирог и переместить в box_1 то вот:

```
box = ['Пирог', 'мороженное', 'вафли']
box_1=[]
box_1.append(box.pop(0))
```

если из box убирать пирог не надо то просто

```
box_1.append(box[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
box = ['Пирог', 'мороженное', 'вафли'] 
box_1 =box [0]
print(box_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно взять только "пирог, то :

```
box = ['Пирог', 'мороженное', 'вафли'] 
box_1 = list(filter(lambda elem:elem == 'Пирог', box))
```

```
box = ['Пирог', 'мороженное', 'вафли'] 
box_1 = [i for i in box if i == 'Пирог')
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй это:

```
box = ['Пирог', 'Мороженое', 'Вафли']
box_1 = []
box_1.append(box[0])
```

Comment: И чем ваш ответ отличается от ранее данного ответа Dedkrut?

Comment: Я не использовал box.pop.

Comment: А зря, в вопросе ТС речь о перемещении.

Comment: Точно, не увидел